# Converting dictionaries to floats where it can be converted

Tags: python, pandas, dictionary

I am looking to create a function which can convert lists which I have imported from CSV's to floats where the number can be converted to a float.

In one CSV the dictionary will look like `['a':'1','b':'1.1','c':'1.2']`, in another it will look like `['1':'1','2':'1.2','3':'1.5']`, and it might also be a combination of the above two `['1':'1','1','2':'1.4','UNKNOWN':'1.4']`

Right now these are imported using `pd.read_csv(SheetAddress, header=None, index_col=0, squeeze=True).to_dict()` however this leaves all of them as strings. I tried to write a function to convert these to new dictionary which contains all of the strings which can be converted to floats to floats and leaves the strings as strings.

```
def DictToInt(DictionaryToConvert, New_Dictionary):
   for Column1, Column2 in DictionaryToConvert.items():
       if Column1.isdigit():
           float(Column1)
       elif Column2.isdigit():
           float(Column2)
```

Which almost works, it converts my dictionary to floats for all of the `[['1':'1','2':'1.2','3':'1.5']` type dictionaries, but for the mixed type it does not work. I have not tested it on a `['a':'1','b':'1.1','c':'1.2']` type yet as it did not work on the mixed, but the solution has to be built with that in mind.

Why is the `['UNKNOWN':'1']` not being converted to `['UNKNOWN':1.0]`, is the logic incorrect in my loop? Is this the right approach for this kind of solution?

Comment: Calling `float(Column1)` doesn't change anything, you need to assign it to something.

Comment: What are you trying to achieve? Do you want to convert only values into floats or both keys and values?

Comment: @Biarys I am trying to convert both keys and values to floats, where they can be converted.

Comment: @hoffee I thought float('1.2') would return 1.2

Comment: @Violatic it does return it, but you dont assign it to anything, so it gets lost

Answer (score 3):

This should do the trick, `data` is your original dictionary, `result` -- well, you've guessed right =)

```
def convert_to_float(num) :
    try :
        num = float(num)
    except ValueError :
        pass
    return num

result = { convert_to_float(k) : convert_to_float(v) for k,v in data.items() }
```

Comment: A bare `except` is not a good idea, as it can catch and ignore errors you don't want to, like `KeyboardInterrupt` and `MemoryError` which can happen anytime. I suggest catching only the correct exception, as in `except ValueError:`

Comment: @nosklo my intent was to give OP the main idea, without overloading with minor details

Comment: it is really important to show beginners how this isn't a good idea, so in this specific scenario I consider even more important to catch the correct exception.

Comment: @nosklo enjoy! =)